# Searching text document

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to search a text document, and I am at a stand still.

**Example of the document:**

```
11/24 05:05:21.781 T0EA8  [PinRegister Version: PINREG 1.2.0]
11/24 05:05:21.875 T0EA8  [RequestPinPadParamEvent: PR_RegDevice = 0.Exit]
11/25 05:04:38.906 T0FB0  [*************************:  ]
11/25 05:04:38.906 T0FB0  [PinRegister Version: PINREG 1.3.0]
```

Now, in that example document, I want to display the 'PinPegister Version' to textbox 'VersionTextBox' from the 25th.

So I am trying to search for the date, then from the date search for the phrase (*'[PinRegister Version: ]'*) and finaly display the results into the textbox (*'PINREG 1.3.0'*).

I have tried alot of options, with nothing working how I want it.

This is my current code, and I feel close... but I am getting an error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

```
Dim strm As IO.Stream = IO.File.OpenRead(fpath)
    Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(strm)
    Dim line As String
    Dim trimchars() As Char = {" "c}
    Dim datelist As ArrayList

    Do While sr.Peek <> -1
        line = sr.ReadLine()
        'If line.TrimStart(trimchars).Contains("[PinRegister Pin Pad Model") Then
        If line.TrimStart(trimchars).StartsWith(TDate.Text) Then
            ' found pattern 
            datelist.Add(line)
        End If
    Loop

    If datelist.Contains("PinRegister Version:") Then
        MsgBox("Found 1")
    End If
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Firstly, you can instantiate StreamReader directly from the path (`IO.StreamReader(fpath)`); and you should put it inside a Using statement to make sure that everything is released properly after being used (and the given file can be accessed in the future without any problems). Secondly, it is not clearly what you have tried. Your code (and, most importantly, the error you are getting) doesn't seem to confirm your "I have tried alot " and " I feel close" claims. It seems that you haven't tried anything. You are not even checking for blank lines (what might be causing your current problem).

Comment: You should already know how SO works. If you are asking about how to extract a certain bit of information, you should have tried something on this front. This code is not doing anything on the extraction front; it is not even able to recognise the line without triggering an error (for a reason you don't know -> this is a second question). I would suggest you to do some work by your own (you might need to do some research/learning too) and I will vote to put this question on hold as off-topic. But who knows? Perhaps, in some minutes someone might come here and write all the code you need.

Comment: Which line is causing the 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error? I'd wager it's on `datelist.Add(line)` because you didn't create a new `ArrayList`. Change the line `Dim datelist As ArrayList` to `Dim datelist As New ArrayList` and that should fix that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just do something like this?

```
  Public Shared Sub FindStuff()
    Dim TextFileLocation = "C:\Test\Test.txt"
    Dim srReader As IO.StreamReader = Nothing
    srReader = File.OpenText(TextFileLocation)
    Do

        Dim strInputFileLine As String = srReader.ReadLine()
        If strInputFileLine Is Nothing Then Exit Do

        If strInputFileLine.Contains(Form1.TextBox1.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Found it")
        End If
    Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how big your input file is, but if its not too large I would suggest reading in all into a string

My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText

and then using a

yourstring.indexof( ...

to find the text you are looking for and work it from there.

I've done this in the past and its quite fast in most cases.